# Assign a random number to a keyframe animation value

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to create an animated background. In short, there are 6 icons which should all animate to move around the page within a small boundary.

Current JS Fiddle works to an extent but need to make amends as below:

### https://jsfiddle.net/mLegg2vt/7/

I wish to randomly generate the movement of these icons so that they bob/hover around within the following bounds:

```
x axis = 1px to 5px
y axis = 13px to 20px
```

I have managed to get a solution using hardcoded values but now think I'm **going about it the wrong way** as it would require **creating multiple keyframe animations** for each icon with different values. I'm not necessarily against this, but I'm not sure how to achieve it.

I have generated random numbers for each icon within the bounds above using the following:

```
var x = randomInt(5, 1); // use this value for x in translate3d
var y = randomInt(20, 13); // use this value for y in translate3d

function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

However I now need to create a keyframe animation for this particular icon using the values created above. At present my hardcoded keyframe animation is used for all icons and looks like this:

```
@keyframes gentleHover {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate3d(5px, 15px, 0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    }
}
```

In the above, I wish to populate the 50% keyframe with my values e.g:

```
50% {
    transform: translate3d(xpx, ypx, 0px);
}
```

Now my question is **how can I do this for each icon, within jQuery?** How can I create a CSS keyframe for each of these 6 icons, with the values? I understand how to add CSS to a particular element with `.css()` but now how to create an entirely new piece of CSS within the stylesheet. I understand I'll then need to add that generated keyframe animation onto this element, but that's easy:

```
$(this).css('animation', '[theCreatedKeyframeHere] 5s linear infinite');
```

*The only way I can think to do this is to put the keyframes wrapped inside `<style>` tags into the stylesheet. But is that recommended?*

It's also important to note all the jQuery above is included in a `site.js` file which is called in via the header. It is not in `<script>` tags on the page.

Comment: Have you looked at [jQuery.Keyframes](https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes)? It might does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I went with the suggestion of using [jQuery.Keyframes](https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes) which allowed me to set keyframe animations in jQuery. Ultimately, it was rather similar to my own solution in that it appends the keyframe to the `head` but it has some extra helpers which makes it easier, so it's well worth a go.

I was then able to generate my random numbers and assign them to `each` icon in the jQuery:

```
$.keyframe.define([{
            name: 'gentleHover'+iconCounter,
            '0%': {'transform': 'translate3D(0px,0px,0px)'},
            '20%': {'transform': 'translate3D('+randomInt(40, -40)+'px,'+randomInt(40, -40)+'px,0px)'},
            '40%': {'transform': 'translate3D('+randomInt(40, -40)+'px,'+randomInt(40, -40)+'px,0px)'},
            '60%': {'transform': 'translate3D(0px,0px,0px)'},
            '80%': {'transform': 'translate3D('+randomInt(40, -40)+'px,'+randomInt(40, -40)+'px,0px)'},
            '100%': {'transform': 'translate3D(0px,0px,0px)'}
        }]);
```

In order to make multiple versions of this, so they are not all the same, I used `iconCounter` which creates a new keyframe animation for every `icon`. I now have `gentleHover1` etc which relate to each icon. The result is that the icons float about in random directions, all differently.

As a way to move on from this it would be cool to add a random number to the seconds timer as well. At present this is 30s for all icons. But having it between 20-40 secs per icon would make some move faster and the intervals be different for each.